# Авто отправка сообщения с файлом aiogramm

Tags: aiogram, aioschedule

Очень часто стал писать вопросы, но меня тревожит последний: как запланировать авто отправку сообщения с файлом ботом, написанным на aiogramm version 3.1.1? Поискал ответы, нашел достаточно но ни один не работает почему-то, можете подсказать? Вот моя функция, которая выдает ошибку что не передан аргумент message, и если возможно, подскажите что ещё добавить чтобы функция точно работала

```
async def morning_newsletter(message: types.Message):
    current_date = date.today()
    today_date = current_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
    file_name = f'schedule/' + today_date + '.docx'
    if os.path.isfile(file_name):
        file_ids = []
        file_from_pc = FSInputFile(file_name)
        result = await message.answer_document(
            file_from_pc,
            caption="Расписание на сегодня"
        )
        file_ids.append(result.file[-1].file_id)
async def scheduler():
    aioschedule.every().day.at("07:00").do(morning_newsletter)
    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def start_tasks():
    asyncio.create_task(scheduler())

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(start_tasks())
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Спасибо за помощь Сергея Ш.

UPD: я разобрался с авто отправкой, только теперь проблема состоит в том, что бот начинает спамить одним и тем же сообщением, которое я указал в функции. Новая правка в функции, которая работает но без остановки в течении указанного времени спамит сообщением:

```
async def evening_mewsletter():
    current_date = date.today()
    tom_not_date = current_date + timedelta(days=1)
    today_date = current_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
    tomorrow_date = tom_not_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
    file_name = f'schedule/' + tomorrow_date + '.docx'
    if os.path.isfile(file_name):
        file_ids = []
        file_from_pc = FSInputFile(file_name)
        result = await bot.send_document(
            CHAT_ID,
            file_from_pc,
            caption="Расписание на завтра"
        )
        file_ids.append(result.file[-1].file_id)
```

Что мне нужно поправить или изменить, чтобы бот перестал отправлять однотипные сообщения на протяжении минуты?